# How do I bind to a WiFi direct discovered service in Android

Tags: android, android-service, android-networking, wifi-direct

I am able to discover local devices via WiFi P2P that advertise an Android service that I am interested in binding to. Once those services are discovered, how do I bind a client to them?

In other words, I'd like to have a client send a `Message` object to a bound service running on a different device, have that device handle the `Message` and potentially respond.

Answer (score 0):

The Android documentation has a training exercise on Wifi P2P [here](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html) and specifically has code to connect to a peer [here](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html#connect)

Comment: I see that.  Once a connection is made, however, how does one bind to the remote service from the local device?  I'm beginning to think such a thing is not possible.  If so, what is the purpose of advertising services in this way?

Comment: It looks like the API guide is more current and discusses transferring data with peers over standard sockets.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html#transferring

Comment: *Message* and *Handler* weren't directly designed to be processed across remote socket connections. You would need to implement the intermediate code (a subclass) if you desire to use Message and Handler.